# c++ program outputs series of numbers instead of cout

Tags: c++, output

My current assignment is to create a simple

***Student Class*** that takes the

```
first name 
last name
student ID number
```

from an object and outputs the name as a single string and his/her ID number. The program also has to count every student and output the total number of students. In this program I'm given 4 students.

I've created the program, given below. Everything compiles correctly and runs but my output is strange. Instead of giving me the students' ID and name, it gives me the number "-858993460". I have no idea why my program's doing this and a long search on the internet hasn't helped me much.

Student.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Student
{
private:
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    int id;
    string name;
public:
    static int numberOfStudents;
    Student();
    Student(string theFirstName, string theLastName, int theID);
    string getName();
    int getID();
};
```

Student.cpp

```
#include "Student.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

//initialize numberOfStudents to 0
int Student::numberOfStudents = 0;

//initialize default constructor
Student::Student()
{
    numberOfStudents++;
}

//initialize overloaded constructor
Student::Student(string theFirstName, string theLastName, int theID)
{
    theFirstName = firstName;
    theLastName = lastName;
    theID = id;
    numberOfStudents++;
}

//getName
string Student::getName()
{
    return firstName += lastName;
}

//getID
int Student::getID()
{
     return id;
}
```

main.cpp(this is my driver file)

```
#include "Student.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Student st1("Hakan", "Haberdar", 1234), st2("Charu", "Hans", 2345), st3("Tarikul", "Islam", 5442), st4;
    cout << "We created " << Student::numberOfStudents<<" student objects." << endl;
    cout << st1.getID()<<" "<<st1.getName()<<endl;
    cout << st2.getID()<<" "<<st2.getName()<<endl;
    cout << st3.getID()<<" "<<st3.getName()<<endl;
    cout << st4.getID()<<" "<<st3.getName()<<endl;

system("pause");
};
```

This is what my output is supposed to look like:
We created 4 student objects.
1234 Hakan Haberdar
2345 Charu Hans
5442 Tarikul Islam
0

This is what my output instead looks like:
We created 4 student objects.
-858993460
-858993460
-858993460
-858993460

I think my problem has something to do with my `getName()` function, but I'm not sure and I don't know what to try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Student::Student(string theFirstName, string theLastName, int theID)
{
    theFirstName = firstName;
    theLastName = lastName;
    theID = id;
    numberOfStudents++;
}
```

Your assignments are the wrong way round. You're assigning the as yet uninitialised members to the arguments. Instead you should have:

```
Student::Student(string theFirstName, string theLastName, int theID)
{
    firstName = theFirstName;
    lastName = theLastName;
    id = theID;
    numberOfStudents++;
}
```

This mistake would have been avoided if you had used a member initialization list instead:

```
Student::Student(string theFirstName, string theLastName, int theID)
  : firstName(theFirstName), lastName(theLastName), id(theID)
{
    numberOfStudents++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the following is the reason for your issues, but it does seem wrong...

```
return firstName += lastName;
```

What this does is modifies firstname by appending last name to it, then returning modified string.

I think you meant to do something like

```
return firstName << ' ' << lastName;
```

Comment: the += is not what i wanted to use, but it seems to be the only method that works. when i try what you've suggested, it gives me an error stating: "no operator '<<' matches these operands."

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to.

```
  Student::Student(string theFirstName, string theLastName, int theID)

{
    firstName = theFirstName;
    lastName = theLastName;
    id = theID;
    numberOfStudents++;
}
```

Your code returning the value of id! which is not initialized.
So the code will return garbage.